# LVM RAID rmeta sub LVs on the same drive

Tags: lvm

I've managed to make a real mess out of my segment layout in LVM. I used to have a couple of LVs but changed it to a single root LV with RAID5 (using `lvmraid`, not `mdadm`). It does work fine however there's one thing which seems a bit concerning to me which is that `[root_rmeta_1]` and `[root_rmeta_2]` are both on the same device. I might have done that accidentally with a `pvmove --alloc anywhere`. It seems to me that they should be on different drives for when a drive fails, is that correct? If so, is there a way to fix this without having to rebuild the VG?

Here's my monstrosity:

```
$ sudo lvs -a -o+seg_start_pe,seg_size_pe,devices --segments
  LV              VG       Attr       #Str Type   SSize    Start  SSize   Devices                                           
  root            pluto-vg rwi-aor---    3 raid5    <4.87t      0 1275802 root_rimage_0(0),root_rimage_1(0),root_rimage_2(0)
  [root_rimage_0] pluto-vg iwi-aor---    1 linear    4.00m      0       1 /dev/sda1(332000)                                 
  [root_rimage_0] pluto-vg iwi-aor---    1 linear   20.00g      1    5120 /dev/sda1(326636)                                 
  [root_rimage_0] pluto-vg iwi-aor---    1 linear  642.05g   5121  164366 /dev/sda1(332001)                                 
  [root_rimage_0] pluto-vg iwi-aor---    1 linear    1.18t 169487  309564 /dev/sda1(0)                                      
  [root_rimage_0] pluto-vg iwi-aor---    1 linear <620.51g 479051  158850 /dev/sda1(624367)                                 
  [root_rimage_1] pluto-vg iwi-aor---    1 linear    4.00m      0       1 /dev/sdc1(952981)                                 
  [root_rimage_1] pluto-vg iwi-aor---    1 linear   20.00g      1    5120 /dev/sdc1(947861)                                 
  [root_rimage_1] pluto-vg iwi-aor---    1 linear   <1.81t   5121  473930 /dev/sdc1(473931)                                 
  [root_rimage_1] pluto-vg iwi-aor---    1 linear <620.51g 479051  158850 /dev/sdc1(215409)                                 
  [root_rimage_2] pluto-vg iwi-aor---    1 linear    4.00m      0       1 /dev/sdb1(5121)                                   
  [root_rimage_2] pluto-vg iwi-aor---    1 linear   20.00g      1    5120 /dev/sdb1(1)                                      
  [root_rimage_2] pluto-vg iwi-aor---    1 linear   <1.81t   5121  473930 /dev/sdb1(479052)                                 
  [root_rimage_2] pluto-vg iwi-aor---    1 linear <620.51g 479051  158850 /dev/sdb1(5122)                                   
  [root_rmeta_0]  pluto-vg ewi-aor---    1 linear    4.00m      0       1 /dev/sda1(803567)                                 
  [root_rmeta_1]  pluto-vg ewi-aor---    1 linear    4.00m      0       1 /dev/sdb1(479051)                                 
  [root_rmeta_2]  pluto-vg ewi-aor---    1 linear    4.00m      0       1 /dev/sdb1(0)                                      
  swap_1          pluto-vg -wi-ao----    1 linear  976.00m      0     244 /dev/sda1(331756)
```

```
$ sudo pvs
  PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree 
  /dev/sda1  pluto-vg lvm2 a--  <3.64t  1.20t
  /dev/sdb1  pluto-vg lvm2 a--  <3.64t <1.21t
  /dev/sdc1  pluto-vg lvm2 a--  <3.64t <1.21t
```

```
$ sudo vgs
  VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  pluto-vg   3   2   0 wz--n- <10.92t 3.61t
```

I tried moving the `[root_rmeta_1]` or `[root_rmeta_2]` sub LV segment:

```
$ sudo pvmove /dev/sdb1:479051-479051 /dev/sdc1
  Insufficient free space: 1 extents needed, but only 0 available
  Unable to allocate mirror extents for pluto-vg/pvmove0.
  Failed to convert pvmove LV to mirrored.
```

---

I suppose it's not possible to merge LV segments in order to make it look a little nicer. I assume that it doesn't affect performance so I'm fine with that. I don't have enough storage capacity outside of this box to copy everything over and rebuild the VG. Might there be other ways that I'm overlooking for rebuilding the VG?